# Open the Android Signing Wizard from a batch file

Tags: android, batch-file, intellij-idea

How can I display the dialog appearing when clicking in Android Studio (IntelliJ) on Build->Generate Signed APK... from a batch file?

I do not want to have a command-line interface for inserting the passwords, I want to display the colorful dialog.
There are several "solution vectors", none of which I succeeded to follow:

1. Find the executable delivered by Android and invoke it from the batch file

   - I did not find it.
2. Check if there is a general mechanism for IntelliJ to invoke action from the command line

   - I found the [Command Line Tools](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/using-command-line-tools.html) but did not understand if they are what I want and how to use them.

**EDIT**: Opening the dialog from batch, a python script or from gradle would also be fine

Comment: write your own dialog and execute the command line signing? Also have a look on "APK Tool", other solution: AFAIK android studio is wirtten in java so you have to look on a .jar file

Comment: Did you try use gradle to build signed apk files? https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/tools/building/plugin-for-gradle.html

Comment: opening the dialog from gradle would also be fine - but it boils down to the same question: how to access the signing wizard from the outside?

Answer (score 2):

Based on information found in the JetBrains article, there is no certain command line to execute this. Of course it is possible to start the program with the "start" command, but other than that, it isn't able to be done.

> On this, last, page of the Wizard, specify the output directory for the generated Android Package. Optionally, have IntelliJ IDEA obfuscate the application through integration with the ProGuard built-in tool.
>   (Quote shows how it is mandatory to use the GUI, not a command line, to generate.)

Site: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/generate-signed-apk-wizard.html

Comment: Thanks for the research (*upvote*) but since the problem could not be resolved, I cannot accept it as the solution :-/

Comment: Of course, I wouldn't blame you if you downvote it after someone gives a legit answer.